# Do a search on more than one table in laravel method request

Tags: laravel

In my project I managed to do a search via request and I wanted to do a search filtered by name (in this case already) and also by reference.
I looked on the internet and nothing that helps me up so far.
I appreciate your help:\

```
else {
            $valida=2;
            $produtc = Produtos::where('nome' & 'refencia', 'like', "%{$tpesquisa}%")->paginate();
            $nrr = count($produtos);
            $msgm = 'Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados ' .$nrr. ' resultados';


            return view('pesquisa', compact('produtc', 'msgm', 'nrr', 'valida'));
```

Comment: `Produtos::where('nome', 'like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->orWhere('refencia','like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->paginate();` try this

Comment: Just to make sure do you want to search on multiple tables or columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong please try with the following way.

```
else {
        $valida=2;
        $produtc = Produtos::where('nome', 'like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->orWhere('refencia','like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->paginate();
        $nrr = count($produtos);
        $msgm = 'Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados ' .$nrr. ' resultados';

        return view('pesquisa', compact('produtc', 'msgm', 'nrr', 'valida'));
```

If you want to do it using **AND** operator then use following code.

```
else {
        $valida=2;
        $produtc = Produtos::where('nome', 'like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->where('refencia','like', "%".$tpesquisa."%")->paginate();
        $nrr = count($produtos);
        $msgm = 'Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados ' .$nrr. ' resultados';

        return view('pesquisa', compact('produtc', 'msgm', 'nrr', 'valida'));
```

Comment: Could you please accept this as the correct answer please so that other will know that this is the solution to such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try I use this when ever i need to do a search

```
Produtos::where(function ($query){
       $query->orWhere('nome', 'LIKE', "%". $tpesquisa. "%")
       ->orWhere('refencia', 'LIKE', "%". $tpesquisa. "%");
})
->paginate();
```

Comment: @Mica g, if it worked you should mark the correct solution as answered

Comment: the option to chew as resolved changed the site ?, I can't find it right now